# Dependency Injection of Singleton Class that extends from Interface

Tags: java, spring

I have a Singleton class `ReadingStratgeyImp` that extends from an Interface `ReadingStrategy`. In `readingStrategyImp-getInstance()` method will return the instance of `ReadingStrategyImp`.

Here is my query:
I want to inject the dependency of `ReadingStrategyImp` in a few of the other classes of the project.
I am achieving this by below code

```
    ReadingStrategy readingStrategy;

    @Autowired
    public void setReadingStrategy(ReadingStrategyImp readingStrategy) {
        this.readingStrategy = ReadingStrategyImp.getInstance();
    }
```

I want to know how one will inject the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do this :

```
@Component
public class Sample {

  // spring will automatically find the implementation class and inject it. 
  // so, the ReadingStrategyImp class will automatically injected. 
  @Autowired 
  @Qualifier("readingStrategyImp")
  private ReadingStrategy readingStrategy;

}
```

That's all.

Comment: If there are two classes that implement ReadingStrategy, I want separate instances of implemented classes.  How this can help in achieving the same?

Comment: @RiaSachdeva You have to use `@Qualifier` for that. Tell me the class name that you have to inject. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I tried the one, but it is not working if the class is a singleton.

Comment: @RiaSachdeva Provide the two implementation class.

Comment: @RiaSachdeva You have to be careful with `@Qualifier` annotation. You have properly use it.

Comment: @RiaSachdeva Provide the name that you gave in the `@Component("some name")` in the `@Qualifier`, if you used.

Comment: I am able to inject the dependency, but I want to access the same instance as the class is a singleton. Here, the issue is every time I auto-wired it create a new instance of that bean. Will edit the code with program structure and results.

Comment: @RiaSachdeva No !! When you autowire, it doesn't create a new instance. In the IOC container, the bean are created at the startup and those beans are singleton in nature. So, you inject the singleton bean only.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help. Your understanding is right.
However, I am still unable to understand what is the use of the singleton pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you should create first a Bean for ReadingStrategy with ReadingStrategyImp:

```
@Bean
public ReadingStrategy readingStrategy() {
   return ReadingStrategyImp.getInstance();
}
```

Then you could just autowire the ReadingStrategy where you need it.

```
@Autowired ReadingStrategy readingStrategy;
```

Its always better to depend on interfaces not on concrete classes.